# Kudan iOS : API key not valid error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, kudan

I'm a beginner to Unity and try to make a simple AR app (IOS).  I set the API key and BundleID in Unity correct and changed the "enable Bitcode" to NO. When I want to build & run the application I got the message:

```
Failed to code sign "Unity-iPhone"
```

"Fix Issue" the following message:

```
An App ID with Identifier 'eu.kudan.ar' is not available
```

I changed the Bundle Identifier to `eu.kudan.ar.*`(and other combinations for the *). This is due to the requirement of wildcard provisioning profile. When the build is ready and the application starts (on the device) the following error occurred:

```
[ line 386] 
(Filename:  Line: 386)

2016-10-03 12:11:50.211 ar[642:224002] Error verifying license key for bundleID: eu.Kudan.Ar23 error: (null)
2016-10-03 12:11:50.211 ar[642:224002] API key not valid
```

I know that wildcard provisioning profile is required and I checked online but I cant seem to make one. I also tried the intel link that was previously mentioned. I am new to iOS. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you been given a key from them? That seems to say your Kudan key is not valid or more likely missing (null).

Comment: When Kudan's tracker initialises, it checks that your Bundle ID and API Key are correct. It is expecting to see "eu.kudan.ar" and the associated key, but it is finding "eu.kudan.ar.*" which does not literally match, so it fails. You do not change the Bundle Identifier in this situation, you have to change your provisioning profile or, if you are using Xcode 8, you can turn on automatic provisioning to fix the problem.

Comment: @Everts Hi, I am using the developement license keys from their website (link : https://wiki.kudan.eu/Development_License_Keys). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Hi, I am using Xcode 8 and the automatic provisioning is turned on. However I still cant use the 'eu.kudan.ar' bundle identifier. I get the following error.

Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "eu.kudan.ar" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Hi, it's because your provisioning profile is not a wildcard. I was incorrect before when I said you could use automatic provisioning, and I apologise. You need a wildcard profile to use a Bundle ID not owned by you.

Comment: @Aniruddha I'm stuck in the same error. Did you get any update? I think  enrolling non-free apple dev account and creating a custom provisioning file would fix this situation, which means $$$..smh.

Comment: @dosuken123 You will need to created a wildcard profile which can be only be possible with a paid apple dev account.                                                  (Just in case) As suggested in some other post, this link by Intel shows how to create a wildcard profile : https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/walkthrough-obtain-dev-provisioning-profile

Comment: @Aniruddha I just got a reply from an official kudan's inquiry forum. As the answer, a paid account is MUST.